# ajax request on link_to with method :put in rails with javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a link which send a ajax request on vote with method put .Its working fine with javascript enabled .So when i disable a javascript it send a get request .I even tried using method post in link_to no luck.Any help would be appreciated ..

routes

```
resources :coupon_votes ,:only => [:voted_down,:voted_up] do 
  member do 
    put 'voted_up'
    put 'voted_down'    
  end
end
```

view

```
link_to(image_tag("coupon/works_yes_icon.png",:alt => "Worked",:size =>"16x15"),voted_up_coupon_vote_path(object.id),:html => {:remote => true, :method=>:put},:id => "voted_up_voted_up_#{object.id}",:class => "working")
link_to(image_tag("coupon/works_no_icon.png",:alt => "Did not work",:size => "16x15"),voted_down_coupon_vote_path(object.id),:remote => true, :method=>:put , :id => "voted_up_voted_down_#{object.id}",:class => "not_working"))
```

controller

```
def voted_up
  comman_vote do 
    @coupon.vote_up(current_user)
  end
end

def voted_down
 comman_vote do 
  @coupon.vote_down(current_user)
 end
end



def comman_vote
  if current_user && current_user.active?
    yield       
  end
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render  "coupon_voted"}
  format.html {render :text => "Thanks for the vote! Please enable javascript to use all the features of the website."}
end
end

def find_coupon
  return if !current_user
  @coupon=Coupon.find(params[:id])
end
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks guys for the effort.I did the other way instead of using remote true in the link_to i did in javascript(application.js) .

views

```
link_to(image_tag("coupon/works_yes_icon.png",:alt => "Worked",:size => "16x15"), "#", :data => {"source" => object.id },:id => "voted_up_voted_up_#{object.id}",:class => "working")
```

application.js

```
$(".working").click(function (){
var coupon_id = $(this).data('source');
var request = $.ajax({url: '/coupon_votes/' + coupon_id + '/voted_down',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'script'
})
return false;
```

});

Comment: buddy you cannot make an asynchronous without being javascript enable, your call itself is remote so it must required javascript

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the method (put) but that the call itself is remote. That implies an asynchronous call and requires javascript.

Comment: can we hack it around so that it can work when javascript is enabled and disabled?

Comment: you could use the `noscript` tag to wrap a _real_ link (that will let your user come to another page upon click) and hide your other link with css and make it visible with javascript when the document is loaded.